# Prove that any function can be written as the sum of an even function and an odd function.

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

I understand some of the basic concepts that surrounds even and odd functions but this question just stumped me and I'm not sure on how to tackle it. Any Starting points/methods would be helpful

Prove that any function can be written as the sum of an even function and an odd function.

Comment: Standard trick:  $$F(x)=\frac {F(x)+F(-x)}2+ \frac {F(x)-F(-x)}2$$

Comment: Hint: not only is this true, such a pair of even/odd functions will be unique. If you assume it is true can you find a solution?

Comment: @lulu what about $f(x)=\ln (x)$

Comment: @mathophile the problem only makes sense for functions defined on the real line, or something like that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Suppose it were true.  What could the functions possibly be?

Let $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$ where $g$ is even and $h$ is odd.

Then $f(-x) = g(x) - h(x)$

And $f(x)+f(-x) = 2g(x)$.  and so $g(x) = \frac {f(x) + f(-x)}2$.

The is indeed an even function that will work, and is apparently a unique such even function.

If we can verify that $h(x) =f(x) - g(x)$ is odd we will have found that not only is this possible, but we will have found a unique odd/even pair for which this can be true.

Now $h(x)= f(x) - g(x) = f(x) - \frac {f(x) + f(-x)}2 = \frac {f(x) - f(-x)}2$ is indeed an odd function.

So we are done:

$f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$ where $g$ is even and $h$ is odd is uniquely expressed when $g(x) = \frac {f(x) + f(-x)}2$ and $h(x) = \frac {f(x) - f(-x)}2$.

Comment: Hello! How does one show/prove the decomposition is unique?

Comment: As $g(x)$ *must* be equal to $\frac {f(x) + f(-x)}2$ and $h(x)$ *must* be equal to $\frac{f(x) - f(-x)}2$ and there can not be any other such functions, the functions must be unique.  That's what unique *means*.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that you can write any function as:

$f(x)= (1 / 2) f(x) + (1 / 2) f(x) + (1 / 2) f(-x) - (1 / 2) f(-x).$

let 
$g(x) = (1 / 2) (f(x) + f(-x)).$
notice that
$g(-x)=(1 / 2) (f(-x) + f(x))=g(x)$

so $g$ is even.

let
$h(x) = (1 / 2) (f(x) - f(-x)).$

notice that $h(-x) = (1 / 2) (f(-x) - f(x))=(1 / 2) (f(x) - f(-x)) = - h(x)$

so $h$ is odd.

Add the 2 functions:
$(1 / 2) (f(x) + f(-x))+(1 / 2) (f(x) - f(-x))=(1 / 2) f(x) + (1 / 2) f(x) + (1 / 2) f(-x) - (1 / 2) f(-x)=f(x).$